# postman create a random decimal value generator

Tags: postman

Please help me to create a decimal value random generator in postman.

```js
pm.environment.set("variable", Math.floor(Math.random() * 50.50));
```

Tried the above code but no use

Comment: I tried your code as well in Postman, and it worked just fine, the variable with the random value was added to the environment.
Did you add it to the pre-request script or the tests?

Comment: Or did you not have the environment created and set in the UI?

Answer (score 3):

it's simple
Just add "true" as third parameter of random's function

Ex: `var decimalRandom = _.random(1,10,true));`

Returns "*8.886340078880954*" i.e

Comment: It doesn't answer the question. You just describe how to create a random decimal with (probably?) lodash. OP never mentioned lodash, and wanted to set an environment variable in Postman.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use Lodash for this as it's a built-in [module](https://lodash.com/docs/#random):

```
pm.environment.set("random_number", _.random(1, 50))
```

Or just add the number 50 to the _.random() function and this will be a number from 0 to 50.

Comment: I would take this as the answer but update it slightly to `pm.environment.set("random_number", _.random(50, true).toFixed(2))` - This will start at 0, add the decimal and cut the decimal places down to 2. :)